# How to put the icons next to the header?

Tags: html, css

I have been writing a website for a while, and I have a small, cosmetic error I want to fix.

That's the code

**HTML**

```
<div id="page">

    <ul id="icons">
        <li><object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/pl.svg"></object></li>
        <li><object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/gb.svg"></object></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <header>
        RYSZARD KUKLIŃSKI
    </header>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.688em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 1px;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 40%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #e60000;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

    border: 5px solid #a20000;
}
#icons {
    list-style: none;

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;

    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#icons li {
    display: inline-block;
}
object {
    height: 16px;
    width: 32px;

}
```

You can also see a live version of the thing I am talking about here: [www.ryszardkuklinski.pl](http://www.ryszardkuklinski.pl) (keep in mind that the site is still in development and it wasn't released, yet), or on the photo below:

[image: Photo of preview]

The problem is with these icons: Polish flag, and British at the top right corner. These icons are placed above the header, and I can't make them being put next to the header. I mean the same level, not under it, and not above. I hope that you understood me. I am waiting for replies :) Generally, the purpose of these icons is to redirect to the site with a different language.

Comment: try absolute positioning for the flags - make `#page` relative and the `#icons {position:absolute; top: 10px; right:5px; }` and remove the margin from icons

Answer (score 1):

Please update the id '#icons' in css with below style.

```
#icons {
    position: absolute;    
    right: 0; 

    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in  :

```
<head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="url of image" type="image/ico" />
</head>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I mean the vector images used as a country flags. look at the photo above, there are two country flags which will be supposed to redirect a user to the site in another language. The thing is that these country flags or icons let's say are not at the same level like "header" tag in HTML. These flags are above the level of the header and that's the thing. I want these country flags on the same level like header. I hope you catch my  drift.